# Enable logical replication on Google Cloud Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, kafka, postgresql-replication

Is there anyway to enable logical replication `wal_level = logical` on Google Cloud Postgres instance? I want to do CDC (change data capture) to stream WAL Record to Apache Kafka.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible.

However, this feature was requested some time ago, and you can track its progression with [this Public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/120274585)

If you click on the star icon on the top left corner of the page, you'll receive important updates on any changes on its status.

Answer (score 3):

This is now in preview:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-logical-replication

"You can use logical replication and decoding features in Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL. These features enable logical replication workflows and change data capture (CDC) workflows."